# Parsing Word Documents Into a DB for Analysis

Tags: database, parsing, solr, ms-word

So there are over 200 documents on this link (http://goo.gl/IdvhMf) each document has over a hundred pages of Questions and Answers from each respondent. Each document represents answers from one respondent. I want to create a table in a db (not dependent on any db technology) that would have a schema something like this:

Respondent | Question Number | Answer

e.g

UBS, 1, "Our opinions is that..."

I can then query the db to say fpr example: "show me all responses from Question 34 for respondents A,B,C"

The step after that might include some for of sentiment analysis on responses.

So what is the best way for someone who is not a programmer by day to to this? Any off-shelf configurable tools I could use?

Answer (score 0):

Split your problem in two.

The first is how you parse out the question and answer pairs from the document.

Storing those in the database is a second unrelated problem.

Addressing the first problem (and not having looked at the documents), that would typically be done on the basis of styles (eg Question style, Answer style), magic text ("Question", "Answer"), or formatting (eg questions are bold/red).  If I had control over the creation of the documents, I'd probably use content controls.

How you do this in code depends to some extent on your preferred language, but things are easier if the documents are in docx format (as opposed to legacy binary doc format, or RTF).  Assuming docx format, there are Open XML toolsets for most languages.